# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' igradeentry.php on line 13

Tags: php

```
<?php
include('../connect.php');
$id=$_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM advisory WHERE tid='$id'");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
$level=$rows['level'];
$section=$rows['section'];
}
echo '<input type="hidden" value="" name="level" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" value="" name="section" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$id.'" name="tidsss" />'
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prereg WHERE level='$level' AND section='$section'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<tr class="record">';
echo '<td  style="border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7">'.$row['fname'].' '.$row['mname'].'     '.$row['lname'].'</td>';
echo '<td><div align="left"><input type="hidden" value="'.$row['idnumber'].'"     name="idnumber[]" /><input type="hidden" value="'.$row['schoolyear'].'" name="schooly[]" /><input type="text" name="grade[]" /></div></td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

i am working on a grade entry system however i encountered this problem this is my data base id,idnumber,level,section,tid,grade,schoolyear column all are varchar except id=int

Answer (score 0):

Check the following line:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$id.'" name="tidsss" />'
```

It should be:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$id.'" name="tidsss" />';
```

(you missed semicolon at the end)

Be careful with similar syntax errors, in most cases the solution is contained in them. Learn how to understand what error/warning messages are saying, otherwise you will lose a lot of valuable time writing on communities than to learn to program.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the advice man. however its not the problem it is saying to me that there is an undefined variable in line 13